# Extract numbers and words from address string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an address string which varies from address to address.

`var address_string = '6-3-54/A/889, Road no 45, Toli Chowki, Bangalore, Karnataka 700065, India'`

How can I separate the following fields from the above address_string using jQuery

```
6-3-54/A/889
Road no 45
Toli Chowki
Bangalore
Karnataka
700065
India
```

Comment: You can split it by comma, but all you have then is an array of strings and you can get parts pf it by indexing the array. Which is going to be of little use in most scenarios. Mark it up before it gets to the page.

Answer (score 3):

Why jQuery?

```
what_you_need = address_string.split(', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split function as below.

```
var arr = address_string.split(',');
```

Access and print as below:

```
      for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      {
          document.write(arr[i]);
      }
```

Please refer [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/QLqGQ/) ( JS Fiddle) will help to solve you problem

You can use below code to get numbers(array) from String :

```
String.prototype.getNums= function(){
    var rx=/[+-]?((\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)([eE][+-]?\d+)?)/g,
    mapN= this.match(rx) || [];
    return mapN.map(Number);
};

var s= 'I want to extract 123 and 456 from this string ';
alert(s.getNums());
```

You can check Length as below :

```
alert(s.getNums()[0].toString().length);
```

// and so on

Comment: Thank you very much nearly there, one of the value in the array has both text and a 6 digit number e.g: Karnataka 700065, how can I detect which value in the array has this 6 digit number and then how can I separate the text and the 6 digit number.

Comment: Karnataka 700065 has 6 digit number,you want to check number value in string?

Comment: I would like to separate number (700065) and the Text (Karnataka). Could you please update your function to suit this ?

Comment: May be you want Some thing like this->http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/QLqGQ/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49807/discussion-between-butani-vijay-and-user44776)

Comment: Click on run during load if appear

Comment: From the values in red (in JS FIDDLE), how can I extract the 6 digit number '700065' (This pincode number is always 6 digits long & is between 100000 & 999999). Many Thanks

Comment: do you have try prototype that i have add in my answer.

Comment: i have updated my answer please check it out. your all solution is there in answer regarding question

Comment: Thanks I shall try this.

Comment: Wish you all the best.hope post will help you